# JAX-RS client Jersey Framework required jars

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jersey-client

What minimum JAR files of Jersey Framework are needed to run a client? 
If I include all JAR's it will take 4 MB.

Comment: It depends on the specific version. For the latest, http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.22.1 lists direct dependencies (which may have transitive dependencies themselves).

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.22.1/jersey/jersey-client/dependencies.html).

Answer (score 1):

Jersey 2.x (2.22.1)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

Jersey 1.x (1.19)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

**Note:** These are just the base client jars. There is no JSON support.

For JSON support, you can add these

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

For Jersey 2, you can register the `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(JacskonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
```

For Jersey 1, you can do

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getClasses().add(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
Client client = Client.create(config);
```

**See Also:**

- [Documentation for 2.x client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html)
- [Documentation for 1.x client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#client-api)

Comment: Thanks all. I'm getting below exception. My REST service response is an "application/xml". Does it require JAXB? Is there any dependencies for JAXB: Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:869)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$800(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$3.call(JerseyInvocation.java:722)

 ..

Comment: I've added javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar and jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar even though the error comes. I'm using latest Jersey.

Comment: You also need [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-jaxb/2.22.1) for JAXB

Comment: I've included JAXB dependencies. Same error is coming at this line in client code: `List<User> users = client.target(REST_SERVICE_URL)
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(list);`

Comment: Thanks it is working now. I missed jersey-media-jaxb.jar.

Comment: Now the JAR's size is 3.36MB. Thanks anyway at-least it reduced some MB.